# show that $e^{f(z)}=\frac{1}{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Clearly, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ has radius of convergence 1. If we let $f(z)$ be the function to which it converges on $|z|<1$, how do we show $\exp(f(z))=1/(1-z)$? I tried expanding the series for exponentials, but that didn't tell me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think your sum should start at $n=1$ instead of $i=0$.

Let $h(z) = (1-z)e^{f(z)}$ and take a derivative.

$h'(z) = -e^{f(z)} +(1-z)e^{f(z)}f'(z)$.

And $f'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ which tells us

$h'(z) = 0$ or $h(z)$ is a constant. Then just set $z=0$ to find that the constant is $1$.